# Unable to find element from script

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I’m trying to get a DOM element from JavaScript. Even though the ID is correct, `getElementId` can’t seem to find it; I get a

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

in Chrome, or a

> TypeError: x is null

in Firefox using only the simple code below. Why is this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var x = document.getElementById("myHeader");
            alert(x.innerHTML);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="myHeader">Click me!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or leave it in the `<head>` but wrap it in a function and call it when `<body>` is loaded

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C/DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/tdt/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function init(){
      var x=document.getElementById("myHeader");
      alert(x.innerHTML);  
    }

//-->
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">

<h1 id="myHeader">Click me!</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using inline attribute event handlers is not considered best practice. It's much cleaner to assign a function directly -- `window.onload = function() { ... }`

Answer (score 12):

Since the `<script>` tag is inside the `<head>` tag, it runs before the body is parsed, so the `myHeader` element doesn’t exist yet.

You need to put the `<script>` block at the end of the `<body>` tag.

Comment: -OR- put the whole shabang in a `document.onLoad` function.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that at the moment you call the `getElementById` function the DOM hasn't finished loading yet, so no element `myHeader` exists. You need to execute this code when the DOM has finished loading. For example:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myHeader");
    alert(x.innerHTML);
};
```

If you use the popular [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) framework, your code might look like this:

```
$(function() {
    var x = $("#myHeader");
    alert(x.html());
});
```

and it will work with most browsers.

Another option is to put your `script` just before closing the `body` tag:

```
<h1 id="myHeader">Click me!</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    var x=document.getElementById("myHeader");
    alert(x.innerHTML);
//-->
</script>
</body>
```

As the DOM is loaded sequentially once your script starts executing the `myHeader` element will already be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Move your script to the bottom in this case, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C/DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/tdt/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>    
<h1 id="myHeader">Click me!</h1>    
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    var x=document.getElementById("myHeader");
    alert(x.innerHTML);
//-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently, it's executing **before the element exists**, so it's erroring because it's not finding anything, and `x` is undefined.  Running your script at the end of the body will resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is running before your HTML is loaded. Move the script to the bottom or delay execution until the page has loaded.

Also, you never need to use `<!-- ... ---->` to hide your script. There's nothing to hide it from

Answer (score 0):

how do you think the browser would know to call your code after clicking the header?
you'd need to extract the alert(something) into a function, e.g.

```
function hello(){
    alert("hello world");
}
```

and to the h1 element add **onClick="hello()"** attribute.

Comment: He isn't trying to make a click event.

Comment: I just thought that the "click me!" header was descriptive enough, that OP was trying to *do* something with clicking it. Way to make a red button that says "Push me", but the operation is in reality in controlled by a remote sensor, duh

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because the browser executes your script immediately upon seeing it, which is *before* your `h1` tag is parsed and added to the DOM.

You could put the `<script>` tag at the end of yoru document, but a better way is to defer execution by putting your alert in the window's `onload` handler.

If you're interested in using a framework like jQuery, it provides a similar `ready` event.